# How to implement this code setDisplayName in my coding android studio project?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i would like to implement my the setDisplayName() into my code but not sure on how to do it. where should i put the setDisplayName inside my code ? 
i want to display the customer name inside my nav bar header.

this is my code

```
//create customer
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Customer info = new Customer(name, email, address, number, gender);

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer")
                .child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid())
                .setValue(info).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Void > () {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Void > task) {
                        regProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class));
                    }
                });
        }
    }
});
```

and this is code that i found but in not sure on how to implement this inside my code.

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            // Sign in is successful
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .setDisplayName(mName).build();

            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
```

this is my Customer java class

```
package com.example.gerobokgo;

public class Customer {
    public String name,email,home_address,telephone_number,gender;

    public Customer(){

    }

    public Customer(String name, String email, String home_address, String telephone_number, String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.home_address = home_address;
        this.telephone_number = telephone_number;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is depend on if user wants to update his name or not. But more importantly what data your passing in your `Customer` in onComplete. Means name and other data.

Comment: i want to display the name into my nav bar header inside my android project

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code flow will be following :

1. User Register with Email and password.
2. Then you set User display name `UserProfileChangeRequest` with FirebaseAuth.
3. After it successfully complete. Your data will be save in Database

   ```
   mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
           if(task.isSuccessful()){
               // Sign in is successful
               FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

               UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                       .setDisplayName(name).build();

               user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                       .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                   Customer info = new Customer(name, email, address, number, gender);
                                   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer")
                                       .child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid())
                                       .setValue(info).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Void > () {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Void > task) {
                                               regProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                               Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                               startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class));
                                           }
                                       });
                               }
                           }
                       });
           }
       });
   }
   ```